# Render form markup outside of an actual form

Tags: forms

I'm creating a form using the form API, and I am loading various things along the way with AJAX. These things function separately from the form itself, but I want them to appear the same i.e. with the same markup as the form fields. Is there any way to render single form elements that don't reference any actual form?

I'm thinking something like the following:

```
render_textfield(
    array('title' => 'Title');
);
```